# UIView animateWithDuration not reacting as I expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm a little confused by UIView animateWithDuration.

I have a label placed at (224,93,152,39), centred horizontally in my storyboard. When I run viewDidLoad, I want it to ***slide up from centre vertically and horizontally*** to the position I've placed in my storyboard. So intuitively, I did this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.titleLabel.frame.origin.x,self.view.center.y, 0, 0);
}];
```

This actually did the opposite for me. The label slides from above the status bar to the desired position (224,93,152,39). I want it to start from centre of the viewController to the desired position (224,93,152,39).

I think I'm not getting something essential of the UIView animations. Would appreciate it if someone can point it out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try by place the above code to viewDidAppear method

Answer (score 1):

The frame you set in the `animations` block is the ending frame.  Set the starting frame right before you call `animateWithDuration` if needed.